# How to convert a base64 encoded string into a ReadableStream?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using a library to upload a file and the documentation says this:

```
channel.sendImage( 
        fs.createReadStream('./helloworld.jpg'), 
        'hello_world1.jpg'
)
```

I don't have a file though, nor am I interested in creating a file, then deleting the file after this function call.

I have a base64-encoded string that I get from another 3rd-party service and I want to pass the base64-encoded string into this function.

The function sendImage takes in a NodeJS.ReadableStream.

Comment: can you post more information about the sendImage function?

Comment: Hi. I found a couple of posts that should get you on the right track but if they don't work, let me know and I'll re-open your question